# How to change default indent in macvim?

Tags: macvim

I am learning to configure the macvim.

Now my tab indent is 4 character, I want to change it to 2. What should I add to the macvim configure file?

Is there any beginner guide for me to learn configure mac vim?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open your $HOME/.vimrc file in MacVim,

```
:edit $MYVIMRC
```

write the following lines,

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
```

and save.

```
:wq
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Kazuki,is any good tuts for more information about setting up the vimrc file?

Comment: How about this? http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/text_editing/vim.html Also :help is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the link you posted here

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It affects vi in the terminal, but macvim still uses tabs.

Comment: Have you checked your setting on MacVim using the following commands?
:verbose set tabstop?
:verbose set shiftwidth?

Comment: It may be worth noting that I also had to set `softtabstop=2` for MacVim to soft-tab correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As Kazuki Sakamoto said above, you need to edit your $HOME/.vimrc file. What you also need to do is make sure that your $HOME/.gvimrc file has these same settings. I use the janus setup with macvim and the only way I could get it to work was to add those lines to that file as well. Having them in both files should ensure that whether you're using vim in the terminal or macvim, the tab settings will be the same.